# How to diplay elasticsearch's terms based on user in grafana?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

i have elasticsearch with Grafana as backend, i would like to add user that has only access to specific terms (and not all of them).

Is it possible to do that? and how ?

Any help would really appriciated

Comment: Do you want to create an Elasticsearch user or a Grafana user?

Comment: In fact i would like to create a grafana user, and that user i do not like him to view all terms of my index displayed in grafana

Comment: Then I can not help you sorry. I could give you advice for elasticsearch/kibana.

Comment: so, is that possible if it was elasticsearch user?

Comment: Yes. I will come back to you after work. In the meantime you can take a look at my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57978433/11486670

Comment: Exactly the second part of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/document-level-security.html that i need, but using Grafana.

Comment: i.e i want when i create user1 then it has access only on docs that has id_doc 10,13,15 only. And user2 has access only to the docs that has id_ot 20, 25 and 26...etc