# Elastic search per user access control to document

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I'm using ElasticSearch `7.1.1` as a full-text search engine. At the beginning all the documents are accessible to every user. I want to give users the possibility to edit documents. The modified version of the document will be accessible only to the editor and everyone else will only be able to see the default document.

To do this I will add two array to every document:

- An array of users excluded from seeing the doc
- An array with the only user that can see the this doc

Every time someone edit a document I will:

- Add  to the excluded users list the user that made the edit
- Create document containing the edit available only to that user.

This way in the index I'll have three types of documents:

1. Documents accessible to everyone
2. Documents accessible to everyone except some users
3. Documents accessible only to a specific users

I use ElasticSearch not only to fetch documents but also to calculate live aggregations (e.g. sums of some field) so query-time I will be able to fetch user specific documents.

I don't expect a lot of edits, less than 1% of the total documents.

Is there a smarter, and less query intensive, way to obtain the same results?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [document level security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/document-level-security.html).

With that you can define roles that restrict the read-access to certain documents that match a query (e.g. you could use the id of the document).

So instead of updating the documents each time via your proposed array-solution, you would instead update the role respectively granting the roles to the particular users. This would of course require that every user has an elasticsearch user.

This feature is the only workaround to fulfill your requirements that **Elasticsearch** brings on the table "out of the box" as far as I know.

I hope I could help you.

Comment: This could work, but document level security do not allow to express the concept "all except some". How do you imagine to implement this? Creating an ad-hoc role each time?